# Is there a directive to detect ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c-preprocessor

I have a code library that works in ASP.NET, the SQL CLR, and stand-alone applications, and provides different features based on whether certain namespaces (such as `System.Drawing`) are available or not. Right now, I'm excluding those pieces of code manually, but it would be beneficial to have the C# compiler to it:

- I could be lazier,
- I could use one and the same library.

I know I can use [`#if` directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx) to search for defines, and I could manually define something like `ASP_NET`, but if there's a way to do this automatically, that'd be even greater.

So, can I detect ASP.NET? Alternatively, can I detect whether certain referenced assemblies are available?

Comment: Why do you want to do it this way? You can certainly use `System.Drawing` from ASP.NET.

Comment: @svick - Because Microsoft specifically say so on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.aspx) (see the caution section). Having said that, I don't know anyone who ran into problems doing so.

Comment: I know I can use `System.Drawing` in ASP.NET. I can't in the SQL CLR, for instance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no such predefined pre-processor directive for asp.net.

What most people do is look for the current [`HttpContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.aspx) - the assumption being that if it is null, this is not a web context.

Another alternative is testing [`HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppId`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.appdomainappid.aspx) for null, to the similar assumption.

Other similar options:

```
System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.IsHosted == true
System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache != null
```

And you can check that a `web.config` file exists.

Comment: No `HttpContext` in WCF, just saying :)

Comment: I'd have to do this during compile time (or fill my code with stub classes) to allow it to compile, which is why I was hoping for something in the preprocessor. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this at compile time (as you said) you can define the preprocessor symbol yourself.

Preprocessing is a C#-only concept. You need to compile once for each target your want to run one. The preprocessor cannot be used for anything that happens at runtime. It's result is burned into the binary.